# Celery AttributeError: async error

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I have RabbitMQ and Celery running locally on my Mac (OS/X 10.13.4), the following code works locally when I run add.delay(x,y):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from celery import Celery
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

app = Celery('tasks', \
        broker='pyamqp://appuser:xx@c2/appvhost', \
        backend='db+mysql://appuser:xx@c2/pigpen')

@app.task(bind=True)
def dump_context(self, x, y):
    print('Executing task id {0.id}, args: {0.args!r} kwargs {0.kwargs!r}'.format(self.request))

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    logger.info('Adding {0} + {1}'.format(x, y))
    return x + y
```

However when I try to run the Celery worker on an ODROID-C2 running Kali 2018.2 (w. current updates, I get the following error when running `celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 14, in main
    _main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 326, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 488, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 281, in execute_from_commandline
    return self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 480, in handle_argv
    return self.execute(command, argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 412, in execute
    ).run_from_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:], command=argv[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 221, in run_from_argv
    return self(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 244, in __call__
    ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 255, in run
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 99, in __init__
    self.setup_instance(**self.prepare_args(**kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 122, in setup_instance
    self.should_use_eventloop() if use_eventloop is None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 241, in should_use_eventloop
    self._conninfo.transport.implements.async and
  File "/home/autossh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/base.py", line 125, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(key)
AttributeError: async
```

From the Kali ODROID I am able to connect to the RabbitMQ instance on the host named c2 using a Python Pika script and mysql from that device works to the c2 machine as well. I have found similar errors, none of those solutions have worked for me.

Celery version installed on the ODROID-C2 via pip is:

```
celery --version
4.1.0 (latentcall)
```

Comment: Slightly unhappy it seemed to break quite a few peoples prod. There are a few GitHub issues about it as well...

Answer (score 104):

We sorted by just updating to celery==4.1.1

it seems the latest release for the 4.1.X sorted out the module name change on kombu

Comment: Please upvote this as this is the correct answer. 
If you set `kombu==4.1.0` and then later upgrade celery, you'll just experience this issue all over again.

Answer (score 27):

Make sure you are using Kombu 4.1.0. The latest version of Kombu renames async to asynchronous.

Comment: I backed kombu to 4.1.0 on that device just to see if it helped, it didn't.

Comment: shouldn't kombu have been upgraded to 5.x?

Comment: The correct answer is @shipperizer below. Instead upgrade to `celery==4.1.1`. If you set `kombu==4.1.0` you'll just encounter this issue again when you upgrade celery past 4.1.0.

Answer (score 14):

Celery does not pin its requirements for kombu and billiard to specific versions. They require the following:

```
billiard>=3.5.0.2,<3.6.0
kombu>=4.0.2,<5.0
```

https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/v4.1.0/requirements/default.txt

kombu 4.2.0 was released with a breaking change and previous versions of celery automatically install it.

Since Celery doesn't pin specific versions, you should pin to the following if you will continue to use celery 4.1.0:

```
kombu==4.1.0
billiard==3.5.0.2
```

Comment: Should be `billiard==3.5.0.2`. Pip install will fail with `3.0.5.2`.

Comment: Thanks, I set my post deploy/fistboot script to install kombu==4.1.0 before installing Celery.

Answer (score 12):

`pip install --upgrade 'celery>=4.2.0rc4'`

`kombu==4.2.0` renames `async` to `asynchronous`, celery fixed it in `celery==4.2.0rc4`.

So you should upgrade celery to 4.2.0rc4.

refer: https://github.com/celery/celery/commit/c8ef7ad60b72a194654c58beb04a1d65cd0435ad

Comment: 4.1.1, which is an official release, fixes it.

Answer (score 6):

That was the issue, it was in fact the kombu version.

I managed to get 2 versions of kombu installed, 4.2.0 as the `'appuser'` user, which I was trying to start the worker under, and 4.1.0 as `'root'`. The 4.1.0 as `'root'` would work, the other user did not.

I removed kombu 4.2.0 from the `'appuser'` user account *(pip uninstall kombu* as that user), so it would use the system-wide installed package, and the Celery worker operated correctly under that account.

To verify that it is in fact kombu 4.2.0 that breaks, I removed the system-wide 4.1.0 version and let pip install the latest version, which it gets as 4.2.0, and the Celery worker would **no longer start**. I uninstalled it and forced pip to install 4.1.0 (*pip install kombu==4.1.0)* and the worker operated correctly.

As another check I went to my Mac, where I originally wrote/tested this code, and checked the kombu version installed there by pip: 4.1.0. I'm not sure why pip on the Mac and Pi3 installed the 4.1.0 version of kombu while pip on the ODROID-C2 installed the 4.2.0 version. I'll dig more if I get a chance but it works now.

Comment: Because kombu 4.2.0 was literally released a few hours before this post. I'm guessing when you installed pip packages w/ `root`, is was pre-4.2.0 release, and when installing w/ `appuser` it was post-4.2.0 release, since as @Daniel says, celery doesn't pin the version, so simply installs the latest version that is <5.0.

Answer (score 0):

A quick hack fix is to disable the result backend:

```
# CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://redis'
```